# Backbone Collection garbage collection stopped by jquery ajax callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I've been messing with Chrome Heap profiler and some basic Backbone objects just to get an idea of garbage collection. I ran into some curious and confusing behavior.

Using a base page that has only jquery-1.7.2,underscore-1.3.3, and backbone-0.9.2 loaded.
If I run the following code from a Chrome (win/19) js console window the collection will  not be garbage collected. In the heap profiler, 'Object's retaining tree' it will list the 50 users and the circular references between the models and the collection, but it will also list 2 that say b in function() @234234. Expanding out those references the references look to be from jQuery's ajax callback handlers.

```
(function () {
    var collection = new Backbone.Collection();
    collection.url = '/api/users/';
    collection.fetch();

    setTimeout(function wtf() { $('#content').append($('<div>' + collection.models[0].get('name') + '</div>')); }, 3000);
})()
```

If I run the following code the collection will be properly garbage collected as expected. The difference is the last line where I make some random ajax call that seems to shift the jQuery ajax callbacks off the collection.

```
(function () {
    var collection = new Backbone.Collection();
    collection.url = '/api/users/';
    collection.fetch();

    setTimeout(function wtf() { $('#content').append($('<div>' + collection.models[0].get('name') + '</div>')); }, 3000);

    $.ajax({ url: '/api/users/' });
})()
```

Is this expected behavior or a bug or what? It'd suck if I have random objects hanging around because they had done ajax requests in the past.

Update: so I was testing this further and it appears to only affect the first or second instances. If I create a setinterval that creates a new collection and calls fetch every 1 second the first 1-2 instances created will remain in memory indefinitely (20min+) while all other instances created will be disposed properly.

If I call jquerys Ajax function and in the success handler hand the data to the new collection as a parameter at creation this behavior does not occur at all. All instances created are cleaned up properly.

It appears that the function Backbone.wrapError is part of the problem along with the wrapping of success.

Comment: I can't answer your question specifically, but I will point out that the Chrome memory profiler can be misleading.  Chrome has an ... advanced garbage collector, and it doesn't always collect everything you would expect it to in a single round of garbage collection.  Rather, it (under some circumstances at least; not sure what those are exactly) it will collect some stuff in round 1, then collect the rest in rounds 2 or 3 (maybe even 4).  I'd recommend keeping that in mind when using the profiler.

Comment: I'd read that somewhere else as well. When your using the timeline view the is a button to force it to garbage collect. I've clicked that button alot in the last couple days :) Also it is showing that the object is being retained because there is a reference to it. If I make the second ajax call that reference gets removed and it gets garbage collected properly.